# loop through a json-Array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, sorting

i have a problem looping through a json-Array with javascript in nodejs.
my array called birthdaysArray looks like:

```
[{"birth":"23.04.1988","name":"Tom Smith"},{"birth":"15.04.2010","name":"Mini Jall"},...,{"birth":"23.04.2001","name":"Michael Bird"},{"birth":"15.11.1999","name":"Frank Middleton"}]
```

now i want to have an array which list the birthdays (sorted by the day of birth) of the **current** month. entries with the same day and month (e.g. 23.04) should be listed in the same date. it should looks like, **if** april is the **current** month (the list has more than 100 entries.):

```
[{"day":"15","name":["Mini Jall"]},{"day":"23", "name": ["Tom Smith","Michael Bird"]}]
```

i looked around, but i don't find a solution for that. 
i checked this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

but didn't match. Who can help ?

attachment 1:
my code in the node_helper.js:

```
    start() {
    console.log("Starting module helper: " + this.name);
    //  console.log("Pfad zur csv-Datei: " + this.path + "/data/birthdays.csv");

    const csvFilePath = this.path + '/data/birthdays.csv';
    csv()
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .then((jsonObj)=>{      
        birthdaysArray = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        console.log("birthdaysArray: " + birthdaysArray);

    var result = Object.entries(birthdaysArray.reduce((a, {birth, name}) => {
        const day = +birth.split('.')[0];
        a[day] = [...(a[day] || []), name];
        return a
    }, {})).map(([day, name]) => ({day, name})).sort((a, b) => +a.day - b.day)
    console.log("sorted birthdays : " + result);
    })
}
```

=> output console.log :

```
  Unhandled rejection TypeError: birthdaysArray.reduce is not a function
at /home/dirk/MagicMirror/modules/perlchamp/node_helper.js:27:47
at Object.onfulfilled (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/csvtojson/v2/Converter.js:112:33)
at Result.endProcess (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/csvtojson/v2/Result.js:83:50)
at Converter.processEnd (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/csvtojson/v2/Converter.js:179:21)
at /home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/csvtojson/v2/Converter.js:172:19
at tryCatcher (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
at _drainQueue (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/dirk/MagicMirror/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

so, what can i do ?

attachment 2:
first I wanted to filter the string by month:

```
        var today_month = moment().format("MM")
        var monthList = [];

        for(let prop in jsonObj) {
            if (jsonObj[prop]["birth"].split(".")[1] == today_month) {
                //console.log("fifth: ", jsonObj[prop]);
                monthList += jsonObj[prop];
            }
        }
        console.log("monthList: ", monthList);
```

...and then apply the code (green hook, the second of them) to it. unfortunately does not work as I had imagined can you do this now in one go? So filter from the annual list of birthdays by the current month, and then display these entries as I mentioned above.

Comment: Your `json` elements do not have an `id`, why do you think logging it would work?

Comment: to be accurate, that is an array of objects - nothing JSON here

Comment: so, you'll want to filter the array for objects whose `birth` property is in the current month, then you'll reduce that array to group people by day of birth, then sort the resulting array to get it in order

Comment: why (in result)  `"name": "Mini Jall"`  and not `"name": ["Mini Jall"]` ?

Comment: you're right, sorry. i will edit it

Comment: @ Jaromanda - EXACTLY right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you changed the expected result - it's a little cleaner

```js
var data = [{
        "birth": "23.04.1988",
        "name": "Tom Smith"
    }, {
        "birth": "15.04.2010",
        "name": "Mini Jall"
    }, {
        "birth": "23.04.2001",
        "name": "Michael Bird"
    }, {
        "birth": "17.05.2001",
        "name": "May Gibbs"
    }, {
        "birth": "04.05.2001",
        "name": "May The Force be with you"
    }, {
        "birth": "17.05.2001",
        "name": "Jenny  May"
    }
];
var currentMonth = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {month:'2-digit'});
var result = Object.entries(data
    .filter(({birth}) => birth.split('.')[1] === currentMonth)
    .reduce((a, {birth, name}) => {
        const day = +birth.split('.')[0];
        a[day] = [...(a[day] || []), name];
        return a
    }, {})
).map(([day, name]) => ({day, name})).sort((a, b) => +a.day - b.day);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry that code don't match. => reduce is not a function.

Comment: @perlchamp --- Run the snippet - works fine ... no idea what you're sayin

Comment: that's what the console print: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: to your information : i want to write a modul for magicmirror, and the code is in the node_helper.js. maybe i have first to send my array to my modulname.js ? i don't know yet.

Comment: @perlchamp - no, the console output in the snippet outputs exactly what you want - if you've copied and changed the code then that doesn't change the fact that `result`, in this answer, is **exactly** what you want

Comment: the console output: [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: yes @perlchamp the console output if you run the code in the answer is exactly what you want

Comment: ok, i want to trust you. i will keep this thread open for some days ... if i make the snippet work, i will mark this topic as done

Comment: the snippet DOES work, it's what you've done at your end that is broken - click "Run code snippet" ... what is the output ... here, on stackoverflow

Comment: yes i can see, great. my code in the node_helper.js:

Comment: @perlchamp *my code in the node_helper.js* ... is it ... right ... so what?

Comment: i wanted to place my code (node_helper.js) right here, but now it's the first code ... sorry for this mistake

Comment: You're stringifying the JSON ... then using array methods on it ... a String (the JSON) is NOT an Array (your jsonObj) ... use `jsonObj.reduce` instead of `birthdaysArray.reduce` - and understand that JSON is purely a String (therefore the variable name `birthdaysArray` is misleading, since it is a String)

Comment: in the code in the ANSWER, `data` is not JSON ... it's an Array of Object, just like your `jsonObj` (another badly named variable by the way) is

Comment: @perlchamp - please don't add answers that are not answers - you could edit your question, and add the extra information in the question itself

Comment: ok, the output now is:    sorted birthdays : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] but that seems to be ok (?).

Comment: depends on how you're `console.log`ing ... `console.log("birthdaysArray: " + birthdaysArray);` will produce that, `console.log("birthdaysArray: ", birthdaysArray);` will produce a better console output

Comment: @ Jaromanda - sorry, it's not exactly what i want, because all month of the year are included and sorted by day of birth. the result should only show the current month ...

Comment: Oh, I thought you had that part sorted, since your sample input only had april - and that part is simple

Comment: I've edited the question, added some May birth dates because it won't work for me, since it's May already @perlchamp

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to create an **Array** of **Object**s who's structure is `[{ day: String, name: [String] }, …]`. Noting that repeated *days* will be grouped into the same **Object** who's *day* indicates the grouping.

The input data is an **Array** who's format is `[{ birth: String, name: String }, …]`.

---

Firstly you will want to extract a meaningful day of the month out of a date string that isn't formatted in a standard way (e.g., `"25.04.1988"`).

To transform this **String** you can use a *regular expression*, with a callback parameter that orders the date in *ISO-8601 Date* format which the *ECMA* standard stipulates that `Date` must support in its construction. Note also that *Date* expects its input to be in UTC time, i.e., it is ignorant of timezone.

Such a construction may look like

```
const input = new Date('23.04.1988'.replace(/^(\d+)[^\d+](\d+)[^\d+](\d+)$/, (...backRefs) => {
    return `${backRefs[3]}-${backRefs[2]}-${backRefs[1]}`;
}));
```

The ECMAScript syntax (which *Node.js* implements) for declaring a regular expression literal is utilised here: `/RegularExpressionBody/RegularExpressionFlags`, where the flags are empty and the expression body is `^(\d+)[^\d+](\d+)[^\d+](\d+)$`.

This regular-expression does not match a valid date, but instead any construction of three series of numerals `(\d+)`, broken by non-numeric characters `[^\d+]` which constitutes an entire **String**. It then reconstructs them using back-references in the order of `3-2-1` with dashes separating them as per the *ISO-8601 Date*'s format.

That is the part `` `${backRefs[3]}-${backRefs[2]}-${backRefs[1]}` ``, which utilises *Template Literals* often referred to incorrectly as *template string*s.

Constructing a *Date* **Object** from this new variable `const input` will work, but it's `toString()` method will return the **String** `"Invalid Date"` if it is indeed, invalid. If the input date does not match the regular expression, such that a back-reference indexes a capture group that doesn't capture; then the *type* of the constructed *Date* is `undefined` as it will be constructed with invalid inputs. This particular result could be used to aggregate invalid birth-dates.

---

Now that you know how to extract the day correctly, you can get to sorting and grouping the inputs.

```
const input = [{
    "birth" : "23.04.1988",
    "name": "Tom Smith"
},
{
    "birth": "15.04.2010",
    "name": "Mini Jall"
},
{
    "birth": "23.04.2001",
    "name":"Michael Bird"
}];
```

Let `input` be your input **Array** of **Object**s.

The **Array** **Object** provides a **Function** called `map` on its *prototype* that you can use on `input` since it is an **Array**. This **Function**'s specification is `Array.prototype.map(callbackFn[, thisArg])`. It is called once for each element that *exists* in the **Array** which is the *object being traversed*. The returned value of the callback replaces the original object in a *temporary* **Array** which is returned by `map` upon completion. In other words, you can map your **Array** into a new structure, by returning that structure from the callback using each element's properties as you iterate. Note that the argument `thisArg` is a context under which the `map` **Function** is invoked, and that if you call `input.map` then the context is inherited as `input` and so, `thisArg` is only optional.

Such an invocation would look like `input.map(argumentsList)` where *argumentsList* is a list that contains only a callback **Function**. The callback takes up to three parameters: currentValue, currentInndex, and the object being traversed.

So your callback should take the form of

```
(curr, idx, arr) => { return…; } // or
function (curr, idx, arr) { return…; }
```

In this callback, you want to transform the `birth` parameter to a *day*, so using the discussed methodology you would do something like

```
let dateCB = ({ birth, name }, idx, arr) => {
    const dateString = birth.replace(/^(\d+)[^\d+](\d+)[^\d+](\d+)$/, (...backRefs) => {
        return `${backRefs[3]}-${backRefs[2]}-${backRefs[1]}`;
    });
    const date = new Date(dateString);
    const retObj = { day: date.getDate(), month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1, name };
    Object.defineProperty(retObj, 'month', { enumerable: false });

    return retObj;
};
```

We add `1` to the month because `getUTCMonth` returns a zero indexed month of the year. Also we define the property `month` to be non-enumerable as we don't want it to show up in the result object. Note also that the `curr` from earlier, is being destructured in `{ birth, name }` and re-structured in `{ day: date.getDate(), month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1, name }`. Destructuring assignment allows you to reduce an **Object**'s *properties* into property names and in the *argumentsList* it declares those properties as variables in the scope of the arrow function. This is actually a shorthand for `{ birth: birth, name: name }` since they have the same identifier as the properties of the input object `curr`.

---

At this point, you will have an **Array** of **Object**s.

```
[
    {
        "day" :23,
        "month": 4,
        "name": "Tom Smith"
    },
    {
        "day": 15,
        "month": 4,
        "name": "Mini Jall"
    },
    {
        "day": 23,
        "month": 4,
        "name": "Michael Bird"
    }
]
```

Except that the `month` properties will not be enumerable.

You want to collate these **Object**s such that the **String** `name` is instead an `Array` of all `name`s who's parent **Object** shares identical `day` and `month` properties with other **Object** members of the **Array**.

So we will look to using `Array.prototype.reduce` which is defined as `Array.prototype.reduce(callbackfn[, initialValue])`. The callback **Function** takes up to four parameters: previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, and the object being traversed. If you provide `initialValue` then `reduce` iterates beginning at the first element, and the `initialValue` is provided to the callback as `previousValue`. However if you omit `initialValue` then `reduce` iterates beginning at the second element providing the first element as `previousValue`. What you return from the callback is then passed to the next iteration as its `previousValue`.

We'll also be using `Array.prototype.findIndex` which is defined as `Array.prototype.findIndex(predicate[, thisArg ])`. The predicate **Function** takes up to three parameters and should return a boolean coercible result (such as `1`, `0`, `true`, `false`, `undefined`, etc). `findIndex` will return `-1` if no predicate returns `true`, or it will return the index it reached when the first predicate does.

We can use this to find out if an array contains a matching `day` and `month` for an iteration of the reducer.

```
({ day: tDay, month: tMonth, name: tName }) => {
    return tDay === … && tMonth === …;
}
```

We want to construct a new **Array** output and we will iterate over the input using `reduce`, constructing the output as we go. For this reason, reduce will be called with an empty array as its optional second argument

```
let reducer = (prev, { day, month, name }) => {
    if (prev.length === 0) { /// this is the first iteration, where prev is empty
        prev.push({ day, month, name: [name] });
    } else { /// this is any other iteration, now we have to search `prev`
        let where = prev.findIndex(({ day: tDay, month: tMonth, name: tName }) => {
            return tDay === day && tMonth === month;
        });

        if (where !== -1) {
            prev[where].name
                .push(name);
        } else {
            prev.push({ day, month, name: [name] });
        }
    }

    return prev;
}
```

And the invocation looks like

```
input.map(dateCB)
    .reduce(reducer, []);
```

---

Lastly we look at the function `Array.prototype.sort` defined as `Array.prototype.sort(comparefn)`. The `comparefn` **Function** receives two arguments, `x` and `y`. The job of `comparefn` is to describe how `x` relates to `y`. The sorter expects a negative **Number** returned from `comparefn` if `x < y`, zero if `x == y` and positive if `x > y`. `x` and `y` are two members of the **Array** being sorted, and so since those members have the same structure you may destructure `x` and `y` as `{ day: xDay }, { day: yDay }` and return `xDay - yDay` for a sufficient result.

---

In this final snippet, I introduce a new variable `cDay` which is just a **String** representation of the `day` property. I also implement the non-enumerable property on the final **Object**s in the **Array** and the sorter on the output.

```js
const input = [{
 "birth" : "23.04.1988",
 "name": "Tom Smith"
},
{
 "birth": "15.04.2010",
 "name": "Mini Jall"
},
{
 "birth": "23.04.2001",
 "name":"Michael Bird"
}];

const dateCB = ({ birth, name }, idx, arr) => {
 const dateString = birth.replace(/^(\d+)[^\d+](\d+)[^\d+](\d+)$/, (...backRefs) => {
  return `${backRefs[3]}-${backRefs[2]}-${backRefs[1]}`;
 });
 const date = new Date(dateString);
 const retObj = { day: date.getDate(), month: date.getUTCMonth() + 1, name };

 return retObj;
};

const reducer = (prev, { day, month, name }) => {
 const cDay = day.toString(10);
 const retObj = { day: cDay, month, name: [name] };

 Object.defineProperty(retObj, 'month', { enumerable: false });


 if (prev.length === 0) {
  prev.push(retObj);
 } else {
  const where = prev.findIndex(({ day: tDay, month: tMonth, name: tName }) => {
   return tDay === cDay && tMonth === month;
  });

  if (where !== -1) {
   prev[where].name
    .push(name);
  } else {
   prev.push(retObj);
  }
 }

 return prev;
};

const sorter = ({ day: bDay }, { day: aDay }) => {
    return bDay - aDay;
};

const output = input.map(dateCB).reduce(reducer, []).sort(sorter);
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: Added that for you. Preferably the way you should investigate "javascript" problems is by probably Googling if you have no idea, and once you get some idea - check the ECMA standard that applies to your Node distribution for any specifics related to how you want to solve your problem. In this case, if you looked up custom sorting of an **Array** of **Objects** you would have found `Array.prototype.sort` and how it works. That should hopefully lead you to other `Array.prototype` **Functions** which do the rest of the grunt work. I did my best to make my answer lead you down that path.